# Gson unicode deserialization

Tags: java, mysql, json, gson, blob

I am reading text from a `longblob` with table-wide default charset equal to ascii and deserializing it with Gson's fromJson(). The charset as given by another field is UTF-8. I want to serialize back a modified version, but I want to test that the serialized version is equivalent to the original text in the longblob - obviously aside from the modification.

```
byte[] words;//from the longblob field using getBytes()
String in = new String(words, Charsets.UTF_8);
MyClass myObj = gson.fromJson(in, MyClass.class);
//modify myObj...
String out = gson.toJson(myObj);
```

The problem seems to be unicode characters. The length of the Strings are not equal due to the affect unicode characters have. For example out as printed will show "we’ll" whereas in will show "we\u2019ll". I know that if I copy and paste these into java code as literals they will be equal and have equal length but in memory they are not equal in the above code.

I prefer a solution that doesn't rely on changing db field type.

Comment: Using ASCII as a charset in 2015? While you'd prefer a solution that does not change the "db field type", it'd be far better and less bug-free in the long run to convert _the whole database_ so that UTF-8 is used...

Comment: If you set the charset to ASCII (just for testing) are they equal?

Comment: No, @JoseMartinez. They are not equal for Charsets.*

Comment: Would it be possible to see the values of out and in?  I really want to solve this.. lol

Comment: This is a SQL insert statement: INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES (X'7B226D657373616765223A2022746F6461795C75323031397320666F6F227D'); The text shows as {"message": "today\u2019s foo"} when fetched and printed as in and shows as  {"message": "today’s foo"} as out